# React-Native wallet

Tags: react-native, wallet

Trying to build a simple react-native feature that can communicate with the wallet (iOS or Android), been trying to use react-native-wallet-manager package but only add to wallet works, I can't get it to identify if pass exists or delete.
I have verified in xCode that the wallet capability is added plus I can see the correct pass type from my Apple developer profile.
Anyone has an actual working example? what am I missing?
Alternatively, is there any other react-native package that works??

Thanks.

Comment: Probably add to wallet works because subtract from wallet might be considered theft?